# convert ascii of every character in string to binary

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, input, binary

So I'm trying to create a program that takes the individual ascii values of characters in a string of user input, adds 1, and converts that new number to binary.

for example, if the user inputs "abcde" I need the output to be

```
1100010 1100011 1100100 1100101 1100110
```

with the binary values separated by spaces like that.  Now, what I have so far is

```
text = input()
for ch in text:
    new = ord(ch) + 1

    decimal = new
    bitString = ''
    while decimal > 0:
        remainder = decimal % 2
        decimal = decimal // 2
        bitString = str(remainder) + bitString

print(bitString)
```

which gives me the binary for the last character input (so if the user inputs "abcde" it gives the binary of the ascii value plus 1), but how can I make it do it for all the characters?

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare `bitstring` as an empty string before the `for` loop starts, outside of it. Otherwise, it gets emptied every time the loop runs and that's why only the last value is printed. You could use the `bin` function as well instead of `ord`, which would immediately give you a binary representation.

Comment: okay, so I put bitString outside the for loop, now the output it's giving me is 11001101100101110010011000111100010.  how do I get the binary values to be separated by spaces?

Comment: Add a space to the bitString obviously... And then when you print it there'll be a space